# Extending Python’s int type to accept only values within a given range

Tags: python, types

I would like to create a custom data type which basically behaves like an ordinary `int`, but with the value restricted to be within a given range.  I guess I need some kind of factory function, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

```
myType = MyCustomInt(minimum=7, maximum=49, default=10)
i = myType(16)    # OK
i = myType(52)    # raises ValueError
i = myType()      # i == 10

positiveInt = MyCustomInt(minimum=1)     # no maximum restriction
negativeInt = MyCustomInt(maximum=-1)    # no minimum restriction
nonsensicalInt = MyCustomInt()           # well, the same as an ordinary int
```

Any hint is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `__new__` to override the construction of immutable types:

```
def makeLimitedInt(minimum, maximum, default):
    class LimitedInt(int):
        def __new__(cls, x= default, *args, **kwargs):
            instance= int.__new__(cls, x, *args, **kwargs)
            if not minimum<=instance<=maximum:
                raise ValueError('Value outside LimitedInt range')
            return instance
    return LimitedInt
```

Comment: Your solution ignores `default`.

Comment: oops, yes, accidentally removed when messing with args. re-added.

Answer (score 1):

Assignment in Python is a statement, not an expression, therefore there's no way to define assignment on a type since assigning rebinds the name completely. The best you could do is define a `set()` method that takes the value that you want, at which point you can just create a "normal" class to handle the validation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to define a new type:

```
def restrict_range(minimum=None, maximum=None, default=None, type_=int):
    def restricted(*args, **kwargs):
        if default is not None and not (args or kwargs): # no arguments supplied
            return default
        value = type_(*args, **kwargs)
        if (minimum is not None and value < minimum or 
            maximum is not None and value > maximum):
            raise ValueError
        return value
    return restricted
```

#### Example

```
restricted_int = restrict_range(7, 49, 10)

assert restricted_int("1110", 2) == 14
assert restricted_int(16) == 16
assert restricted_int() == 10
try: 
    restricted_int(52)
    assert 0
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can derive a class from an `int` in python e.g. `class MyInt(int)`, but that type in python is immutable (you can't change the value) once it's created.

You could do something like this though:

```
class MyInt:
    def __init__(self, i, max=None, min=None):
        self.max = max
        self.min = min
        self.set(i)

    def set(self, i):
        if i > self.max: raise ValueError
        if i < self.min: raise ValueError
        self.i = i

    def toInt(self):
        return self.i

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        # Forward e.g. addition etc operations to the integer
        #   Beware that e.g. going MyInt(1)+MyInt(1) 
        #   will return an ordinary int of "2" though
        #   so you'd need to do something like 
        #   "result = MyInt(MyInt(1)+MyInt(1))

        method = getattr(self.i, name)
        def call(*args):
            L = []
            for arg in args:
                if isinstance(arg, MyInt):
                    L.append(arg.toInt())
                else: L.append(arg)
            return method(*L)
        return call
```

It may be better to use ordinary validation functions depending on what you want though if it's simpler.

**EDIT**: Is working now - Reverted back to a simpler earlier version, having addition etc functions which return other MyInt instances just isn't worth it :-)

Comment: `# Beware that e.g. going MyInt(1)+MyInt(1) will return an ordinary int of "2" though` Not if you `return MyInt(getattr(self.i, name), max, min)` :)

Comment: @bp: that won't work, as `getattr()` returns a function and not an integer. It would be possible to return a function which converts the result to a MyInt later though, you're right!